# Copy SQL Stored Procedures between DataSources/Schemas?

Tags: stored-procedures, schema, datasource, ibm-midrange

I've created SQL stored procedures in our development schema and its working fine. Now we are in the task of moving our development codes to production one. How do I copy those stored procedures from one schema to another schema? Do I need to re-compile whole procedures on targeted schema? Or Is there any way register those procedures on targeted schema? Could any one suggest me a better way to copy stored procedures?

I've created procedures through iSeries Navigator for Windows Version 5 Release 4.

Thanks in Advance,
Suresh

Answer (score 4):

The SQL to create your stored procedures should be in source files as part of a project in some  source control system (CVS, SVN, etc.).

To "deploy" your project to a new server (Dev, QA or Production) should simply require executing those "source SQL" files on the new server / database.

Indeed, any changes to the database (table columns altered, new tables added) should be in SQL files in source control, and applied the same way.

Although the database development tools don't always make it seem like it - SQL is source code too. :-)

Comment: Yes, You are right.But How to register/execute these procedures to prod scheme thru iSeries commands without using external database development tools? i.e without physically executing all sql files. Simply transfer to prod schema as a qualified stored procedures.

Comment: I put the SQL to create tables, indices, etc. into normal source files with the source type as SQL.  Then I change my current library to the production data library or whatever and run the SQL with the RUNSQLSTM command.

You can easily add it to PDM... I use RS for the option and "RUNSQLSTM SRCFILE(&L/&F) SRCMBR(&N) COMMIT(*NONE)" as the command.  That lets you run it against everything all at once if you want.

Comment: Yes in a perfect world it should. But if you have a bone-headed project manager who just creates these here and there and leaves no source behind, it would be nice to have a fairly automated way of copying them over to a new db.

Answer (score 1):

In general, original source isn't needed. Open iSeries Navigator and drill down through Databases to the schema that holds the development SPs. Select all of the ones you want, right-click and select 'Generate SQL'. Choose to open in 'RunSQL Scripts' (and optionally include DROP statements).

That will give you a script of all selected SPs in one place. This can be stored anywhere you choose. Also, you can use Edit-> Replace if any schema names need to be changed in the script.

Then you can take menu option Connection-> Use Temporary JDBC Settings... to point to the new schema. And finally, click the Run All icon on the toolbar to generate the SPs from the script into your new schema.

In short, select the ones you want into iNav 'Run SQL Scripts', point to the new schema and create them in essentially a single operation.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the link ,This might be helpful.
http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2005/12/31/change-schema-name-on-tables-and-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best way (so far) that I've found was working with SQL Management Studio, and using the Script Procedure As ... menu options. This will produce the SQL source for your sprocs (CREATE/ALTER depending on which menu option you use)

If you need to bulk-copy all the sprocs/user defined functions, use the Tasks->Generate Scripts menu option. In the resulting series of dialogs, you can choose which sprocs/functions to generate scripts for, then run those scripts on your new db.